# Recursion in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I'm new to Ocaml and i'm trying to write a recursion function.

The function take a list of pairs and return a pair of lists, for example

```
[(1, 4); (2, 3); (5, 9); (6, 10)]) -> ([1; 2; 5; 6], [4; 3; 9; 10])
```

But the compiler say that: `Error: This expression has type 'a list * 'b list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a list`

in the line `(unzip (List.tl m))`

Can someone explain why I have this error please? And is there anyway to fix this? Thank you very much!

```
let rec unzip m =
    if List.length m = 0 then
       ([], [])
    else
       ((fst (List.hd m)) :: (unzip (List.tl m)), (snd (List.hd m)) :: (unzip (List.tl m)))
in 
    unzip m;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any recursion, you have to note that the output type will be always the same.

Let's see your `unzip` function.

`[(1, 4); (2, 3); (5, 9); (6, 10)]) -> ([1; 2; 5; 6], [4; 3; 9; 10])`

Simply say, the return type of `unzip` is def **a pair (tuple)**, and each element is a list, correct?

---

Then let's see your code

```
let rec unzip m =
    if List.length m = 0 then
       ([], [])
    else
       ((fst (List.hd m)) :: (unzip (List.tl m)), (snd (List.hd m)) :: (unzip (List.tl m)))
in 
    unzip m;;
```

You have two branches. First branch is returning `([], [])`. Ok, in terms of return type, it is correct as it is a pair with two empty lists and matches the return type described above.

---

The second branch

`((fst (List.hd m)) :: (unzip (List.tl m)), (snd (List.hd m)) :: (unzip (List.tl m)))`

is it correct?

It is a pair with two elements, no problem, then let's see the first element:

`(fst (List.hd m)) :: (unzip (List.tl m))`

You are trying to add `(fst (List.hd m))` to the head of `(unzip (List.tl m))`.

But you can only add something to a list by using `::`, so ocaml supposes `(unzip (List.tl m))` is a list, right?

But it is a `unzip` function application, apparently described in the beginning, your `unzip` is not returning a list, but a pair (tuple).

So ocaml doesn't understand and thus complain.

---

The above is just to answer your question about the type problem. But your code has more problems.

**1. incorrect use of `in`**

Suppose you have a function `f1`. You can image it as the mother function, which means it can be used directly. Also in `f1`, you can declare another function or variable (or more formally, a binding). Only when you declare a binding inside a function, you use `let...in...`. If you only have the mother function, you don't use `in`, because `in where`?

In your `unzip`, you only have one function or binding which is `unzip` itself and it is in top level. So `in` is not necessary.

**2. incorrect logic of recursion**

I don't know how to explain to you about recursion here, as it needs you to read more and practise more.

But the correct code in your idea is

```
let rec unzip = function
  | [] -> ([], [])
  | (x,y)::tl -> 
    let l1, l2 = unzip tl in
    x::l1, y::l2
```

If you are chasing for better or a tail-recursive version, here it is:

```
let unzip l = 
  let rec unzip_aux (l1,l2) = function
    | [] -> List.rev l1, List.rev l2
    | (x,y)::tl -> unzip_aux (x::l1, y::l2) tl
  in 
  unzip_aux ([],[]) l
```

Comment: You are so good!! Thank you very much! When I read about the pattern matching and recursion, they are quite similar, actually they are same i think, but different in format of code

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that `(unzip ...)` returns a pair of lists (`'a list * 'b list`), which you try to manipulate as a list when you write `(fst ..) :: (unzip ...)`.

This would all be written much more nicely if you used pattern-matching. Skeleton:

```
let rec unzip = function
  | [] -> ...
  | (x,y) :: rest ->
    let (xs, ys) = unzip rest in ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I have seen the pattern matching and understand it, but is there anyway to fix that code?

Comment: Yes, use `let (xs, ys) = unzip (List.tl m) in ...` in your code.